# Python: how can I differentiate between two variables of two different objects of the same class?

Tags: python, class

I have a problem with a task for school. I want my last method to test if two rectangles are the same. The only problem there is that I can't seem to differentiate between the two different heights, widiths and the different point(this is the left-low corner point of the rectangle) of the two different rectangles, any advice?

Thanks a lot

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self,Point,w,h):
        self.Point=Point
        self.widith=w**strong text**
        self.height=h

    def same(self,Rectangle):
        if Rectangle.self.Point==self.Point and Rectangle.self.widith==self.widith and Rectangle.self.height==self.height:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the same name for the `Point` argument `(__init__(self, Point...)` and the `class Point` (I'd do `__init__(self, point, w, h)`) And then I'd take a look to the `__eq__` method (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) of the class. If you overwrite it in you `Point` and `Rectangle` classes, you can use `rectangle1 == rectangle2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use the same name for function params and classes. It makes the code confusing and error prone. Try this:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, point, width, height):
        self.point = point
        self.widith = width
        self.height = height
```

Now I assume that `point` variable is an instance of `Point` class. In that case comparing one point to another via `==` will fail, because by default `==` checks if two objects are the same in the sense of being the same object in memory.

Thus your implemenatation of `same` method may look like this:

```
def same(self, other):
    return (
        self.point.x == other.point.x
        and self.point.y == other.point.y
        and self.width == other.width
        and self.height == other.height
    )
```

---

If you overwrite builtin `__eq__` method (which is responsible for the behaviour of `==` operator) on `Point` class like this:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
```

then `same` method can be simplified to:

```
def same(self, other):
    return (
        self.point == other.point  # now __eq__ will be called here
        and self.width == other.width
        and self.height == other.height
    )
```